# How to select SQL Server 2008 uniqueidentifier and put it in a .net Guid variable?

Tags: .net, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I am having trouble SELECTing a column of type `uniqueidentifier` and putting it in a variable of type `Guid` in ASP.net.

The database is generating the `uniqueidentifier`, and all I want to do is pull them out and store the values in case I need to populate a foreign key table.

I am using a private member to store the value:

```
Private _uniqueID as guid
```

I `SELECT` from the table and use a `SqlDataReader` called `vRdr`. All the other values are coming out just fine, but when I add this I get an error:

```
if not isDBNull( vRdr("uniqueID")) then
    _uniqueID =  vRdr.GetGuid("uniqueID")
end if
```

The error I get is

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I am not sure why I am having so much trouble trying to select these values. I have also tried `Guid.Parse()` and `Guid.TryParse()` on the data reader value with no luck.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getguid.aspx), GetGuid() takes a column ordinal, not a string key. Change your code to this:

```
_uniqueID =  vRdr.GetGuid(vRdr.GetOrdinal("uniqueID"))
```

Comment: Awe, that's the sort of learning that doesn't scale well beyond RTFM. Thank you, this works.

Comment: Post your code and any errors as a new question, and we can take a look at resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new `Guid` from your database value?

Example:

```
_uniqueID = New Guid(vRdr("uniqueID").ToString())
```

Comment: I had tried new Guid( "" & vRdr("uniqueID")) but not .ToString( ). Your code works, but another correct answer was first. I don't think I can check both.

Comment: I agree mgnoonan's answer is a better solution.  Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling [GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getordinal.aspx)() in a loop (for X records in a result set), this can be very costly. You'd want to save off the value of GetOrdinal() once and reuse.

Or, you can use the `[]` operator on `IDataReader` and index in given the string identifier for your column. This return an `object`, but simply cast it to a Guid. Note that indexing by string also calls GetOrdinal, at least in `SqlDataReader`.

```
Guid myGuid = (Guid)vRdr["uniqueID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

often times many procedures works out for many versions of .net framework. Below is the two solutions that actually worked for me visual studio 2012.

1. ViewState("Guid variable") = ("Guid value")
2. Dim myGuid As Guid
   myGuid = ("Guid value")

The first solution retains the variable data after page postback while the second does not. Enjoy!